# python 3.5.0 ::: Compare values inside lists with each others

Tags: list, python-3.x, indexing

I want to compare vogals that I put in one variable, and see if they are not the same. I only want to output the vogals that exist in that variable, but I don't want it to appear the same vogal multiple times.

**My code:**

```
lista = []
for vogal2 in palavra:
    if vogal2 in 'aeiou':
        lista.append(vogal2)

x ='0'
for val in lista:
    y = lista.index(val)
    if val == x:
        lista[y] = []
    x = val
print (lista)
```

**The output:**

```
>>> Enter a word: inconveniente
['i', 'o', [], 'i', 'e', 'e']
```

**I want the output this way:**

```
>>> Enter a word: inconveniente
['i', 'o', 'e']
```

*Can you help me? I'm using python 3.5.0*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a different code doing the same thing:

```
word = input("Enter a word: ")

output = []

for letter in word:
    if letter in "aeiou" and not letter in output:
        output.append(letter)

print(output)
```